# Websockets with proxy

Tags: proxy, websocket

I'm unable to get my application utilizing web sockets to work.

I have a site www.example.com which uses an anti-DDoS service so it resolves to IP X.X.X.X. The real address of the server is Y.Y.Y.Y. The anti-DDoS service does not proxy web sockets traffic so I wanted to stream it directly to the real address (it's difficult to find it for attack in reality so this will work) so what I did is instead of pointing it to ws://www.example.com:100/, I pointed it to ws://Y.Y.Y.Y:100/.

Now if I access my application by the real IP (http://Y.Y.Y.Y), it connects to ws://Y.Y.Y.Y:100/ just fine but if I use http://www.example.com link (which resolves to X.X.X.X), ws://Y.Y.Y.Y:100/ won't connect saying "WebSocket connection to 'ws://Y.Y.Y.Y:100/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

I guess this has something to do with security but I don't know what exactly. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the websocket server sees the domain in `Origin` HTTP header different than the domain in the `Host` HTTP header and it is refusing the connection because of that. The `Origin` header is usually used to figure out if the connection is coming from an allowed website, since websockets are not under the Same Origin Policy.

The request that works will look like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: YYYY
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://YYYY
```

The request that is refused will look like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: YYYY
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://www.example.com
```

It is hard to tell with this little information. Don't you get any error in the server logs?

Comment: Here's the traffic I caught using Fiddler: CONNECT Y.Y.Y.Y:100 HTTP/1.1
Host: Y.Y.Y.Y:100
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36

Comment: Response: HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2016 16:02:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 19:02:10.161

[Fiddler] The connection to 'Y.Y.Y.Y' failed. <br />Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). <br />System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it Y.Y.Y.Y:100

Comment: There's nothing in server logs, probably these types of issues are suppressed by the framework I use (Fleck).

Comment: You can add custom logging to Fleck : https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck#custom-logging

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't look like the request even reaches Fleck because these are the only lines in the log: 11/29/2016 7:50:55 PM [Info] Server started at ws://127.0.0.1:100 
11/29/2016 7:50:55 PM [Info] Server started at wss://127.0.0.1:85

Comment: But if I connect using telnet from my machine, I get this: 11/29/2016 8:24:08 PM [Debug] Client connected from A.A.A.A:47262 
11/29/2016 8:24:26 PM [Debug] 0 bytes read. Closing. 
 so it is available. Can it be browser blocking things up? Or maybe some policies?

Comment: Or even a firewall in your machine or the server. It is hard to say.

Comment: I extended Fleck logging and from what I see, it builds response and tries to send it. It then fails on reading data from the stream with this: 01.12.2016 20:11:11 [Debug] HandleReadError start 
01.12.2016 20:11:11 [Debug] Swallowing ObjectDisposedException System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endMethod, TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs)

Comment: On your first comment, that HTTP request you put is not a WebSocket request, it is a regular HTTP request that will never convert into a WebSocket. Maybe that is the reason why Fleck is crashing trying to handle the connection. Why that CONNECT request is being made rather than the websocket GET request is what you need to figure out. CONNECT is something you send when you are behind a proxy and you want the proxy to connect you to your target, but it is not intended to be handled by the websocket server.

Comment: sorry, here's the right one: GET http://Y.Y.Y.Y:85/ HTTP/1.1
Host: Y.Y.Y.Y:85
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://www.example.com
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Sec-WebSocket-Key: IAHYp0Mej81p/4LzFHFeGg==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits

Comment: response caught by Fiddler: HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 20:32:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 23:32:27.900
[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.

Comment: Log from Fleck: [Debug] Client connected from 95.161.223.60:7114 
[Debug] 517 bytes read 
[Debug] Building Hybi-14 Response 
01.12.2016 23:32:22 [Debug] Sent 129 bytes 
01.12.2016 23:32:22 [Debug] Sent 4 bytes 
01.12.2016 23:32:22 [Debug] Swallowing ObjectDisposedException System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endMethod, TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs)

Comment: Would you mind to try with a different websocket server? I develop one myself: https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/

Comment: will it work on .NET Framework 4 (I'm on Windows 2003)? Does it support legacy connectivity using Flash?

Comment: Humm... I am afraid not :( It requires .NET 4.5

Comment: damn :(. Created one more topic on this with all details, hopefully someone will have ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931159/fleck-objectdisposedexception-when-connection-is-not-direct